# Amount of Decoupling Capacitance in Integrated Circuit Layouts

Tags: integrated-circuit

When doing integrated circuit layouts, how does one pick the amount and value of the decoupling capacitance ?

When doing over 10GHz designs, I typically EM simulate the supply line and use the resulting RLC value to determine the decoupling capacitance.  I look at the lower frequency response around DC and look for ringing especially if I use MIM caps which are higher Q versus MOS capacitors.  If I have ringing in my response what do I do?  Do I de-Q the capacitance of the MIM capacitors using resistors?  Or just use MOS capacitors?

When doing lower frequency RF or analog IC designs, I would just let the RC extraction help me with the supply lines and so on and then determine the capacitance that way.

Is this thinking/methodology/flow correct for these different frequency designs?  How best to determine the amount of decoupling capacitance on chip?

Answer (score 1):

It is very normal to add some series resistance with your decoupling to damp the response. You should simulate this WITH your package inductance and determine how much series resistance you need. The exact amount of peaking you can tolerate will depend very much on your circuit. Key parameters to look out for are the affect of decoupling network peaking on noise and jitter.

For example, for 10GHz I suspect you are probably designing RX amplifers? In such an application there is  great benefit by reducing the decoupling response peaking as excessive peaking increases deterministic jitter in the RX chain. But doing this will degrade HF response ofcourse because the series resistance limits its high frequency attenuation , so add some broadband decoupling aswell. So simulate key parameters such as this as a function of decoupling R and C. I am surprised you need to full EM simulate at 10 GHz, so perhaps RCC extraction with bonding wire inductance will suffice for faster runs.

EDIT:
Regarding your comment for MIM vs MOS, you have to be careful as it is not simply a matter of Q. MIMs will give you the most linear capacitors and low voltage dependency so they are always a good choice however, the density is often lower than MOS caps specially in a thin oxide process. It is also not uncommon to have series resistance with MOS capacitors to damp the response.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  To add this additional resistance to damp the response, can I just add some interconnect, which itself will have some resistance instead of adding on chip resistors - just to save space ?  And yes, this is for a RX application.  I typically EM simulate over 10GHz just to be sure about capturing the full RLC responses.    When you say "broadband decoupling" what do you mean by that ?  How do I do broadband decoupling - I have never heard of this statement.  I find most of the ringing is at lower frequencies in my design (under 500MHz) just as a comment.

Comment: You will probably need a few ohms. Can you guarantee and characterise interconnect resistance accurately across corners? Probably best to stick to poly if not.

Comment: If you add a series resistance to a capacitor you cap (no pun intended!) its high frequency attenuation. So you should never only have such decoupling. A smaller capacitor without additional added ESR is also good to make sure HF noise is also decoupled.

Comment: How do I do broadband decoupling - I have never heard of this statement.

Comment: Most of the ringing I see in my design (Wideband Amplifier from DC - 40G) is at lower frequencies under 1 GHz.    On chip I only have MIM and MOS Cap in this process so I can't really control the resistance of them apart from adding resistance myself in the form of on chip resistors or interconnect resistance - isn't that correct ?

Comment: Yes add some series resistance, keeping an eye not to degrade high frequency attenuation. Chip resistors (like poly) are probably a better choice as you are likely to have more specifications for them.

Answer (score 0):

Lets think about those MOS caps.

For low-ringing, set R = sqrt (L / C); thus 1nH and 10pF need sqrt(1e-9/1e-11) or sqrt(100) or TEN ohms, for low-ringing.

You can design the series resistance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fepZvh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

now what is the series resistance if the well sheet-resistance is 1,000 ohms/square
with just one contact and for this (almost square) aspect ratio.

Looks like about 1,000 ohms to get from lower-left corner of the well, over to the middle of the well under the middle of the gate-poly material.

To reduce this (we are ignoring the gate-poly sheet resistance), we need a long thin layout, with many well-contacts along the bottom of the well.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to be clear about the schematic that you just posted.  The "contact" you mention there, the well-contact and the gate-contact - you mention there is "one and only one".  Are these vias inherent to the MOSCAP in the PDK ?  I just wanted to be clear what you meant by "contact".